# Xebium stable for regression testing?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, fitnesse

I'm an Test Engineer for a software company and I'm busy with writing a regression tests. During the execution of the tests using Jenkins I noticed that there are some stability problems. I'm quite new here and I was hoping if you guys are having the same problems or have some suggestions for me?

I'm using Xebium to communicate between ‘Selenium’ and ‘Fitnesse’ and I'm writing my scripts in Selenium IDE. Fitnesse is being used as a web server and a wiki what is also available on the virtual machine. Jenkins checks the repository out and makes a copy of the tests and they will be executed on that VM so that Jenkins creates a Job of it.

After some updates on:

- Selenium IDE 2.9.0
- Selenium 2.52.0
- Jenkins ver. 1.643
- Java version jdk 1.8.0.74
- Selenium.version 2.52.0
- Fitnesse.version 20151230
- Xebia.incubator 0.14-SNAPSHOT

it is getting better but I still have some stability issues.

Can somebody help me?

Regards,
Patrick

Comment: I think people will be able to help you better if you could specify what the 'stability issues' you experience are exactly.

Comment: Stability problems are e.g. :timing issues: __EXCEPTION__:java.lang.AssertionError: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Element is not clickable at point (997, 34.5). Other element would receive the click: <div style="z-index: 1040;" modal-backdrop="" class="modal-backdrop fade in" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1040 + (index &amp;&amp; 1 || 0) + index*10}"></div>
Command duration or timeout: 101 milliseconds. I already use step "wait for element present so it should be find right?

Comment: Also when I select a radiobutton then it is deseleted again without having that step in script.

Comment: Scripts are working just fine for a long time and then suddenly they are not working. But after a while they start working again. Without changing something.